# unable to find timezone in django

Tags: python, django, linux

### What I am doing.

I am working on a very basic django project.

### what is my problem.

When I am loading my webpage (locally) it is showing following error on webpage.

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator
```

and error that I saw on terminal is

```
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key utc'
```

Comment: You could add `USE_TZ = False` to the `settings.py` or fix the timezone as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 1):

Running the command below in the terminal should fix the issue:

`pip3 install tzdata`

or

`pip install tzdata`